# Apply Scaling to a 3 Dimensional Numpy array of variable sized arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to apply column-wise scaling of a 3 Dimensional Numpy array containing variable sized arrays.

The array looks like

```
[
 [
  #c1,c2,c3
   [1,2,3],
   [4,5,6],
   [7,8,9],
 ],
 [
   [1,2,3],
 ],
 [
   [1,2,3],
   [4,5,6],
 ]
]
```

The number of columns is always same (like 3 in example above)

The Scaling I'm trying to apply is

```
mean = X.mean(axis=(0,1))
X -= mean
std = X.std(axis=(0,1))
X /= std
```

Since the X here doesn't contain same sized arrays the above approach doesn't work (It does work on same sized)

My expected output of `mean` is

```
>>>mean
[mean of column1, mean of column2, mean of column3]
```

That is for column 1

```
mean = (1+4+7+1+1+4)/6
```

and so on for other columns and similar in case of `std`

I have found [numpy.ma.mean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.mean.html#:%7E:text=Returns%20the%20average%20of%20the,not%20finite%20will%20be%20masked.) but this includes introducing additional size that I can not because my `X` is already huge and I don't have the  memory to store the additional overhead.

Is there any efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they have same number of columns, you can simply vertically stack them and calculate your mean (and you need axis 0 for column-wise mean):

```
mean = np.vstack(X).mean(0)
#[3. 4. 5.]
std = np.vstack(X).std(0)
#[2.23606798 2.23606798 2.23606798]
```

If you are fine with stacking them, you can do `X -= mean`, if not, need a simple loop to do it.(or if it is too large of an array, stack, subtract and de-stack them)

Comment: By *simple loop* did you mean something like `for index in range(len(X)) : X[index]-=mean`

Comment: @skrrrt Or even `X = np.array([x-mean for x in X])`. sidenote, I would also add an extra dimension to mean just to be safe.